# Function not being called, no console log

Tags: javascript, react-native, function

I am new to javascript and react native, but trying to get better by working on a project.

I am trying to call some functions (viewHandle, editHandle, deleteHandle) onItemClick event but they are not working, trying with a console log.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, View, Animated } from 'react-native'
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Context as TrackContext } from '../context/TrackContext'


import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const TrackListScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const { state, fetchTracks } = useContext(TrackContext)

  viewHandle = (item) => {
    console.log('click on view id', item)
  }

  editHandle = (item) => {
    console.log('click on view id', item)
  }

  deleteHandle = (item) => {
    console.log('click on view id', item)
  }

  const rightSwipe = (progress, dragX) => {
    const scale = dragX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [1, 270],
      outputRange: [0, -1],
    });
    return (
      <>
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.3} onItemClick={this.deleteHandle}>
        <View style={styles.deleteBox}>
          <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{scale: scale}]}}>
          <MaterialIcons name="delete" size={37} color="red" />
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    
      
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.3} onItemClick={this.editHandle}>
        <View style={styles.editBox}>
          <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{scale: scale}]}}>
          <MaterialIcons name="edit" size={37} color="grey" />
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      
      
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.3} onItemClick={this.viewHandle}>
        <View style={styles.viewBox}>
          <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{scale: scale}]}}>
          <MaterialIcons name="preview" size={37} color="grey" />
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </>
    )    
  }
```

Comment: Remove the `this` from the `onItemClick` props. You should/can only use `this` with class components, and your component in the example is a functional component. [Here is a primer](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) from the docs. :)

Comment: this key is used in class components. remove this key in functional components when calling handlers.